# How to set <select> as disabled or readonly in jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to set select tag as disabled or readonly in jquerymobile?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Comment: Use the disabled and readonly attributes. Standard HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html) method helps

> **disable** 
>   disable a select.
>   `$('select').selectmenu('disable');`